# turn column of numbers into comma separated list

Tags: python, list, csv

Hi I have data like this

```
40
50
70
```

I want output like this:
40,50,70

I have tried:

```
from sys import argv
script, pos_file, output = argv
positions = []
with open(pos_file) as f:
   for x in f:
      positions.append(x)
print positions
```

It gives me a list like '40\n', '50\n', '70\n' so it is treating the numbers as strings and printing the line deliminator \n.  How can I modify this code to do what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out for myself as follows incase it helps anyone else (slightly cheated by treating my column as a csv file):

```
from sys import argv
import csv
script, pos_file, output = argv
positions = []
out = open(output, "w")

with open(pos_file, "rb") as csv_file:
     f = csv.reader(csv_file)
     for x in f:
         positions.append(x[0])
     print ",".join(positions)

out.write(",".join(positions))
```

Comment: 'code'  from sys import argv
script, pos_file, output = argv
positions = []
with open(pos_file) as f:
 for x in f:
  
  x.rstrip("\n");
  positions.append(x)

 
intpos = [map(int, x) for x in positions]

print intpos
print pos

Answer (score 0):

You could have worked with your original code. You needed to add one line, to remove the new line character.

```
from sys import argv
script, pos_file, output = argv
positions = []
with open(pos_file) as f:
   for x in f:
      x.rstrip("\n");
      positions.append(x)
print positions
```

The last line prints a list. In your second code, you made a string instead of a list.

Comment: how can I loop through this - eg: for x in positions:    print x if x < 1000

Comment: @SamLipworth `for x in positions: if int(x) < 1000: print x` (Add proper python formatting)